# Why do I have a ghost file to n my Ubuntu server?

Tags: server, 18.04

I recently came across this problem:

I wrote a RoR deployment script, a standard bash script which checks for directories, clones codes and runs a few commands. Before it starts modifying the file system, it creates (using "touch") a file (named deploy.lock) which is checked for existence by the script so that two instances of the deployment script do not run simultaneously. It removes the file in the last step to make sure a second run of the script could be made.

I am calling the script using

`ssh user@server.example.com -tt /home/user/scripts/deploy.sh`

However, if I am already logged into the server in another SSH session and try to run the deployment twice, the second (and subsequent) run fails complaining that the deploy.lock file exists. If I check the file (using ls) from the second SSH session then the file is not listed and in the next attempt to run the deployment, there is no such problem occurs (deploy.lock file is not detected).

Why is this happening?

Comment: Try `flock` instead

Comment: What's flock? I know it's a browser. I don't think you meant that. Link to it, please?

Comment: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/en/man1/flock.1.html